# Nginx. Something like drupal in root and Magento in subfolder

Tags: magento, drupal, nginx, url-rewriting, subdirectory

In root directory I have Drupal. In sub directory I have Magento. Most probably drupal rewrites overlap magento rewrites.

Magento homepage opening successfully without any nginx config, but links don't work.

**I'm not sure, but I think to resolve the problem I need exclude magento directory from drupal routing.**

**And another thing is, I'm not sure if I have proper magento config.**

> root config:

```
server {
    listen  80;

        root /var/www/domain;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name domain.com;

    location /fe {
        proxy_pass http://domain.com:1234/visualization;
    }

    location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /var/www/domain;
        }
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9$
        location ~ \.php$ {
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;

                 }
```

> magento config

```
    server {
        listen 80;
    ## SSL directives might go here
        server_name domain.com; ## Domain is here twice so server_name_in_redirect will favour the www
        root /var/www/domain/magento;

        location / {
            index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
            try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
        }

        ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
        location ^~ /app/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /includes/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /lib/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /report/config.xml { deny all; }
        location ^~ /var/ { deny all; }
##      location ~ /\.ht { deny all; }

        location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
            auth_basic "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
            auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
            autoindex on;
        }

##        location /.
        location ~ /\.ht { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
            return 404;
        }

        location /api {
            rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest last;
        }

        location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
            rewrite / /index.php;
        }

        location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
            rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
        }

        location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
            if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

            expires off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
##          fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8079;
        ##fastcgi_read_timeout 10800s;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
            fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
            include fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is use some subdomain for magento, like https://shop.yourdomain.com. But if you want to keep it as http://yourdomain.com/magento you need to remove separate nginx config file for Magento and add /magento/ location to root config. I mean:

```
location /magento/ {
    root /var/www/domain/magento; #main thing
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
}

location ^~ /magento/app/ { deny all; }
location ^~ /magento/includes/ { deny all; }
location ^~ /magento/lib/ { deny all; }
location ^~ /magento/media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
location ^~ /magento/pkginfo/ { deny all; }
location ^~ /magento/report/config.xml { deny all; }
location ^~ /magento/var/ { deny all; }
location ~ /magento/\.ht { deny all; }

etc.
```

Then you need to check Magento Secure/Unsecure URL. It should be http://yourdomain.com/magento/ You can change it via admin panel or directly in database (core_config_data table). In the end clear the cache and restart Nginx.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I have already tried this. In other words its config merge, right? Is there any possibility to have two configs? Does it make sense?

Comment: No, it's not config merge. You just don't need 2 configs for one domain name. In your case Magento placed in subfolder so describe it in Nginx config as location /subfolder/ ...

Comment: Yes, but the main problem is that website from root belongs to another department and maybe they will need to edit their nginx config. That because I'd like to separate. Messages like 'DO NOT EDIT THIS SECTION' is not very good idea :)